# WPF show image in listbox error

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I would like to show images to listbox from folder, but in WPF I'm a beginner so I found this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18561/Custom-ListBox-Layout-in-WPF

**XAML**:

```
   <UserControl.Resources>        
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4"
          CornerRadius="5" Margin="6"
          >
                        <Image
            Source="{Binding Path=UriSource}"
            Stretch="Fill"
            Width="100" Height="120"
           />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider
  ObjectType="{x:Type local:UserControlTest}"
  MethodName="LoadImages" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Code behind:

```
 public static List<BitmapImage> LoadImages()
    {
        List<BitmapImage> robotImages = new List<BitmapImage>();
        DirectoryInfo robotImageDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"..\folder");
        foreach (FileInfo robotImageFile in robotImageDir.GetFiles("*.jpeg"))
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(robotImageFile.FullName);
            robotImages.Add(new BitmapImage(uri));
        }
        return robotImages;
    }
```

but I have a **error**:

*Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.*

Meantime I tried to open Exception Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>) and check all checkbox, but still nothing.

**EDIT:**

I tried to comment my method in Code Behind and error was same, so **problem will be in XAML**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the LoadImages method into a static class (not on your usercontrol class) and use the name of the static class instead.

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        
}

public static class ImageLoader
{
    public static List<BitmapImage> LoadImages()
    {
        List<BitmapImage> robotImages = new List<BitmapImage>();
        DirectoryInfo robotImageDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"..\folder");
        foreach (FileInfo robotImageFile in robotImageDir.GetFiles("*.jpeg"))
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(robotImageFile.FullName);
            robotImages.Add(new BitmapImage(uri));
        }
        return robotImages;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border
                        Margin="6"
                        BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="5"
                        >
                        <Image
                            Width="100" Height="120"
                            Source="{Binding Path=UriSource}" Stretch="Fill"
                            />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="LoadImages" ObjectType="{x:Type local:ImageLoader}" />
</Window.DataContext>

<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that pops out is this line:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=UriSource}"/>
```

Since the DataContext itself should be a `BitmapImage`, try replacing it with

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=.}"/>
```

The recursion is caused by the constructor of the MainWindow.
ObjectDataProvider generates a new instance, which generates a new ObjectDataProvider, etc...

Put your LoadImages Method in a separate class.

```
public class ImageLoader
{
    public List<BitmapImage> LoadImages()
    {
        List<BitmapImage> robotImages = new List<BitmapImage>();
        DirectoryInfo robotImageDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures");
        foreach (FileInfo robotImageFile in robotImageDir.GetFiles("*.jpg"))
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(robotImageFile.FullName);
            robotImages.Add(new BitmapImage(uri));
        }
        return robotImages;
    }
}
```

And change your XAML to

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.DataContext>
        <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="local:ImageLoader" MethodName="LoadImages"/>
    </ListBox.DataContext>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thx. I changed it but still nothing. My investigation: Problem will be in `<Window.DataContext>` because I create new solution and I tried to add only this part of code and error is same **code sample:** `<Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindow/>
    </Window.DataContext>`... so where can be a problem?

Comment: If you want to set the Window itself as DataContext, use this instead: `DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`

Comment: I found the source of your StackOverflowException, The ObjectDataProvider instanciates a new MainWindow, which itself does the same. I'll post a working example shortly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a static LoadImages method, you should implement the MVVM pattern and create a view model with a property that provides the image (path) list:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> ImagePaths { get; private set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public void LoadImagePaths(string path)
    {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.jpg"))
        {
            ImagePaths.Add(file.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

In the constructor of your MainWindow or UserControl you would create an instance of that view model, assign it to the `DataContext` and call its `LoadImagePaths` method:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;

    vm.LoadImagePaths(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures");
}
```

Your XAML would look like shown below. Note that `Source="{Binding}"` directly binds the `Image.Source` property to a path string, which is then automatically converted to type `ImageSource`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ImagePaths}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```